# Python converting string to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the problem with converting [those text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGF3.png) from strings into columns.
**my code:**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import csv

with open("base.txt", "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="/t")
    allData = [(str(first), int(second), str(third), str(fourth)) for first,second,third,fourth in reader]
print(allData[0])
```

I need to split content like [by first (w/o numbers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7BU8.png), [second only numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIgg2.png), etc. Not by string but columns.

Comment: your data looks to be common delimited, but you open it with tabs `delimiter="/t"`.  edit: oops that's not even tabs, because tabs would have the slash going the other direction `\t`

Comment: Are you asking how to transpose the data?

Comment: Voting to close as typo -- The input file is comma-delimited, OP is trying to separate by `"/t"`. Do `reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=",")`

Comment: @Barmar https://prnt.sc/131r68w i've got problem like this

Comment: That's because you're giving the wrong `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: Use `delimiter=', '`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/131rcjm i neet get all the data from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7BU8.png as [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can split your code to cells (of a matrix), assuming columns are separated by `,` and rows by new lines.

```py
with open("base.txt", "r") as in_file:
    mat = [line.split(',') for line in in_file]
```

Adjust column count inequality between rows, if it exists, i.e. your data is like this:

```
A, 0, X
B, 1
C, 2, Y
```

By doing:

```py
# Be sure "mat" is not empty or a ValueError is raised
column_count = max(len(row) for row in mat)
for row in mat:
    if len(row) < column_count:
        row.extend([None] * (column_count - len(row)))
```

Then you can access each cell as `mat[row][column]`.

If you strictly need to your data in column-major order (grouping columns together), simply find the transpose of the above matrix.

```py
mat_T = [[mat[row][column] for row in range(len(mat))] for column in range(len(mat[0]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the mixed format of your input data, pandas might be a good tool to use:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('base.txt', sep=',', 
       index_col=[1],    # 2nd column are indices so use this rather than creating new index
       names=('A', 'B', 'C')  # Change this to the names for your data, excluding the index column
       parse_dates=['B'])  # the 3rd column looks like dates/times to me
```

Comment: can i refuse from index_col, 2nd column isn't indices but numbers of labs, number of which may be random like 546, 111, 2321?